# Automatically run Excel VBA macro when cell value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro that calls another macro when the value in cell A1 changes.
At the moment I am using the following code, but it seems to call the "pageupdate" sub every time the page recalculates, rather than just when the value in A1 actually changes from 0 to 1.

Does this issue stick out at anyone who understands the "Worksheet_Calculate" sub type or the logic behind the if statement.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    '|-------------------------------------------------|
    '|        Run Pageupdate                           |
    '|-------------------------------------------------|

    'If cell A1 recalculates affected by a change in the sheet/s, then this macro runs the 'PageUpdate' Macro.
    'The point of this is to prevent the PageUpdate running when it doesn't need to.

    Static OldVal As Variant
    If Range("A1").Value <> OldVal Then
        OldVal = Range("A1").Value
        Call PageUpdate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print OldVal, Range("A1").Value` then check the output after a few updates - is it what you'd expect?

Comment: Where would I put this? Thanks

Comment: Right before the `If` statement

Comment: Fully qualify the `Range("A1").Value ` to be `Me.Range("A1").Value `, if another sheet forces the calculation, the you may be looking at the wrong value. Might not be the current issue, but worth doing as a general discipline thing.

Comment: Also consider "Application.EnableEvents = False` when running `PageUpdate` because this may also cause A1 to recalculate (maybe not currently, but who knows what happens after a future VBA edit) so you don't go into an endless loop.

Comment: `Call` is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

- Add the following sub as a Macro attached to the sheet you want to be
  affected by the update and put your code inside this macro.
  [You can find the solution here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel)

  > Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  >       Dim KeyCells As Range
  >
  > ```
  > ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
  > ' cause an alert when they are changed.
  > Set KeyCells = Range("A1:A1")
  >
  > If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
  >        Is Nothing Then
  >
  >     ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
  >     ' changed.
  >     ' Place your code here.
  >     'MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
  >
  >     End If
  > ```
  >
  > End Sub

Comment: I have tried this one before I posted, but doesn't seem to work

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is not triggered if a change is due to a formula calculation